# Check user's "clearance level" before acessing a page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm kinda new to node.js so my problem is simple:

I have this function in my routes file that checks if a user is authenticated

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        console.log(req.user);
        return next();
    }
    req.flash('warn_msg', 'Login required');
    res.redirect('back');
}
```

What I need is a similar one, that also checks the user "clearance level".

Here's what I wrote:

```
function isLevel(clearance, req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        if(req.user.level>=clearance){
            return next();
        }
        else {
            req.flash('warn_msg', 'Not enough permissions');
            res.redirect('back');
        }
    }
    else {
        req.flash('warn_msg', 'Login required');
        res.redirect('back');
    }
}
```

The problem is that the first one I can use like this

```
app.get('/newOrg', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('Orgs/newOrg');
});
```

But I don't know how to pass the 'clearance' argument to the second, and calling it like this

```
app.get('/newOrg', isLevel(3), function(req, res) {
    res.render('Orgs/newOrg');
});
```

Gets me an error saying 'req' is undefined

I know I can work around and check the user level inside the get route, but I wanted a "cleaner" solution

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you can't pass it like that. You could save it to a session property, and then in `isLevel` check the session property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When express loads up the routes, it looks for middlewares which should be references to function. Here you are putting `isLevel(3)`, essentially calling the function and putting the result of the function as middleware.

You need to put reference to function. You can do it by creating a function like this

```
function checkLevel3(req, res, next) {
  return isLevel(3, req, res, next);
}
```

And then use `checkLevel3` in place of `isLevel(3)`.

You can also create a high order function, that can spit out functions like `checkLevel3` on demand

```
function leveler(n) {
  return (req, res, next) => isLeveL(n, req, res, next);
}
// now
const checkLevel3 = leveler(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the function, but you need to pass a reference to it so express can call it when it needs to. So to pass values arround you need to do one of two things.

You can add a new object to req for temporary usage, or use `express-session` for a more "permanent" usage between multiple requests. It looks like `express-session` would be best in your situation.

It would look something like this

```
const session = require('express-session')

// Setup session management
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))

// Set the session
app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
    req.session.clearance = 3
    res.redirect('/newOrg')
})

// Run isLevel
app.get('/newOrg', isLevel, (req, res) => {

})

// Get the session
function isLevel(clearance, req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.clearance)
}
```